# Get Current Time Milliseconds

Tags: delphi

How to get current time in milliseconds? I know to use **`Now`**, but I need to get the time in milliseconds.

```
var
  today : TDateTime;
begin
  today := Now;
```

Comment: People below are guessing, because your question is not clear. I can tell you it's today, 9AM. Now, express me that moment *in milliseconds*.

Comment: Your request is imprecise. Milliseconds with respect to what epoch?

Comment: i need to store server response time in milliseconds when the server response, i want to get current time in ms

Comment: Well, then it sounds you are looking for a way to calculate number of milliseconds between the time when you do the request and the time when the response arrives. For that is the `MilliSecondsBetween` function. But if you don't need to rely on `TDateTime` type, e.g. if that timestamp is not a part of the response content, you can simply use `TStopWatch` in recent versions of Delphi, or subtract values obtained by `GetTickCount` calls, for example.

Comment: `GetTickCount` suffers from wraparound.

Comment: @David, you don't need to worry in case of one wrap (which should be enough for request/response I hope :)

Comment: @TLama If the machine has been up for 49 days then wrap is a real concern, even for a quick response

Comment: @David, subtract e.g. `20-(MAXDWORD-10)` (where 20 is the value after wrap, `MAXDWORD-10` before wrap) to see my point. The risk is there, but after more than one wrap.

Comment: @TLama Written like that it's a compiler error because the compiler tries to perform the calc with the true constants. Written using variables it is integer overflow with my preferred compiler settings. So at least you need to suppress overflow checking, and be sure of how the compiler handles overflow. I'm sure it's not in any language spec.

Comment: Guys idk what are you talking about but i just wanted to simple little milliseconds :/

Comment: @David, even I would fail on integer overflow. That was a bad example, but it's easy to workaround. I'll keep saying that the risk is there for more than one wrap.

Comment: @TLama I agree. But it is something that one should be conscious of at least

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Windows 95 solved that very effectively. It was restarted every 49.7 days :-)

Comment: To avoid the overflow issue, you can use [`GetTickCount64()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724411.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
DateUtils.MilliSecondsBetween(Now, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the DateUtils [MilliSecondOfTheDay](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.MilliSecondOfTheDay):

```
ms := MillisecondOfTheDay(Now);
```

> Returns the number of milliseconds between a specified TDateTime value and the beginning of the same day.

Should you want the milliseconds from another time frame, there are other similar functions like: `MilliSecondOfTheYear`, `MilliSecondsBetween`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

DecodeDateTime will take a TDateTime and be able to split it up into Year, Month, Day, Hour Minute Second and Millisecond.

See http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DecodeDateTime for more info.

Once you have the individual numbers, you can use math to calculate the current millisecond count past midnight.

```
Var
  myDate: TDateTime;
  myYear, myMonth, myDay: Word;
  myHour, myMin, mySec, myMilli: Word;

begin
  myDate := Now;
  DecodeDateTime(myDate, myYear, myMonth, myDay, myHour, myMin, mySec, myMilli);
  ShowMessage('Number of milliseconds past midnight = ' + IntToStr(myMilli + (mySec * 1000) + (myMin * 60 * 1000) + (myHour * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

A TDateTime is a `double` where 1 is a day.  The SecsPerDay constant declared in SysUtils represents the number of seconds in a day, so to get Now in milliseconds:

```
todayInMilliseconds := Now * SecsPerDay * 1000.0;
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Not every day has the same count of seconds. For example the day, on which the clock is changed to daylight saving time, contains 1 hour less. And constant `SecsPerDay` will be not valid in this case.